# NSNotification sends value that get reset in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have this problem:
2 views called **A** and **B**, both are `TableViewController`.

**A** listen for notification, **B** sends notification

I'm not going to explain in detail, but for sake of simplicity it's like this:

**A** can display multiple types of data, **B** has a list of these types, selecting one row from **B** makes **A** load in it's `tableView` the right list of data.

While i'm in B i'm sending a notification like this

```
NSNumber *section = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:section
                                                               forKey:@"CurrentTableView"]

NSString *UpdateTableView = @"UpdateTableView";
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UpdateTableView
                                                            object:self
                                                          userInfo:infoDictionary];
```

Now in A i'm listening like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateTableView:)
                                                 name:@"UpdateTableView"
                                               object:nil];
```

which calls the method

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *section;

// :::: Some code here ::::

- (void)updateTableView:(NSNotification*)note
{
    _section = [[note userInfo] valueForKey:@"CurrentTableView"];
    NSLog(@"%d",[_section intValue]);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and the `NSLog` works fine, i mean it prints the right value.
I'm using `_section` to discriminate in the TableView delegate methods what kind of data to load.

The problem is that the call to this method (after the notification is received) happens BEFORE the view is actually reloaded (viewDidAppear and so) which set my `@property _section` to 0, in this way every time my TableView loads the data standing behind the `[_section intValue] == 0`.

How could i solve this? I need something that don't gets reset every time the view loads itself. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**: navigation controller to move from B to A

```
MenuNavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

AViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];
        navigationController.viewControllers = @[homeViewController];
```

Comment: You're explicitly setting the value to 0 in viewDidAppear?

Comment: no i don't set it to any value.

Comment: what are you trying to do with _section ? Can't you pass an object with your notification ?

Comment: @Justafinger in the delegate methods for the `tableView` i'm using _section to check what type of data to display. something like `if(_section == 0) load this...else if(...)` and so on. the notification passes the data correctly, because logging it it displays the right value, but the the page is loaded and _section is set to 0 (should it be the default value?)

Comment: How do you navigate from B to A ? NavigationController ?

Comment: @Justafinger i'll edit first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need NSNotification ? Notifications are used where you want to update a view, and by update i mean that the view is already created.

What i would do is fairly simple, in B i would set your `NSNumber *section` as an ivar (if you display controller A some place different from where you post you notification). When you posted your notification you would just instantiate your ivar.

Then A would have a similar variable and when you want to display A :

```
AViewController *homeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];
homeViewController.section = section;
navigationController.viewControllers = @[homeViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your property `section` isn't synthesizing to use your instance variable `_section`. Does your synthesize line look like this:

```
@synthesize section=_section;
```

Otherwise the compiler will implicitly create an instance variable name `section`

UPDATE

As @Justafinger mentioned, as of Xcode 4.4, the ivar will be named `_section` if you completely leave out the `@synthesize` line. If you do explicitly synthesize, however, and don't assign the ivar name in the `@synthesize` line the ivar name will default to `section`.

Comment: This line is useless since Xcode 4.4, a property is automatically synthesized with this ivar name.